# Laravel Model creation override

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my Laravel project, I have different user types that all have a base User model. Here's a brief idea of the database topology:

```
users:
 - id
 - name
 - email

students:
 - age
 - user_id

teachers:
 - budget
 - user_id

employee:
 - is_admin
 - user_id
```

In my case, each of `Student`, `Teacher`, `Employee` has their own `User`. But if I want to make a new `Student` for example, I have to make both a `Student` and `User` model. I'm aware of the Observers pattern in Laravel which can make this job easier, but I'd like to be able to programatically make `Student` models like the following:

```php
$student = App\Student::create(['name' => 'Joe', 'email' => 'joe@example.net', 'age' => '20']);
```

The problem gets even more complex from there, because `Teacher` models are also required to have both an `Employee` model and a `User` model. Is there a way to override the `create` method on my model so that I can pass in `User` creation parameters, but also `Student` parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `create` method and do this yourself. In your `Student` model class add this:

```
public static function create($arr) {
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $arr['name'],
        'email' => $arr['email']
    ]);

    $student = parent::create([
        'age' => $arr['age']
        'user_id' => $user->id
    ]);

    return $student;
}
```

You can do other methods in a similar way.

If you Laravel version is above 5.4.* do this instead:

```
public static function create($arr) {
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $arr['name'],
        'email' => $arr['email']
    ]);

    $student = static::query()->create([
         'age' => $arr['age']
         'user_id' => $user->id
    ]);

    return $student;
}
```

Comment: Ahh nice. I've seen the `parent` static method in Laravel before. Any reason not to use it compared to `static::query()`?

Comment: Above Laravel 5.4.*, `Model::create` &`Model:: forceCreate` methods have been moved to the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` class in order to provide better support for creating models on multiple connections.